# ¿Cómo puedo pasar parametros a un evento?

Tags: c#, eventos, parametros

estoy intentado programar un menú contextual para interactuar con las celdas de un `DataGridView`, pero no sé cómo pasarle un parámetro a la función a la que suscribo el evento del ítem del menú contextual:

```
private void dgv_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
                cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("showChild",pClick));
                int currentMouseOverRow = dgv.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
                cm.Show(dgv, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            }
        }
        private void pClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            MessageBox.Show("msg");
        }
```

¿Cómo podría pasarle al método pClick el valor de la celda clickada en `dgv_MouseClick`?
Seguro que hay formas más simples de conseguir lo que quiero, es por aprendizaje, ¿cómo puedo resolver una situación así?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: en sender tenes el objeto que llamo a ese evento.. y en e tenes los argumentos del mouse.. ahi ya tenes toda la info que queres...

Comment: Lo estoy intentando, pero creo que no acabo de entenderlo, el MenuItem es que el está suscrito al evento pClick, por lo que el sender serà este item, no veo como puedeo pasarle el valor de la celda :_

Comment: ahhhh es mas complejo.. tenes que guardar la info de la celda al mostrar el menu... asi ya sabes donde mostro el menu ;)

Comment: mmmmm, pero guardarlo donde? en alguna propiedad del MenuItem ?

Comment: Creo que ya veo, la propiedad Tag puede contener cualquier objeto...